# Insert a pattern before another one

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

I have a line looking like this:

```
pattern1 any text pattern2 any text pattern2 any text pattern2 any text
```

And I want it to become:

```
pattern1 any text
pattern1 pattern2 any text
pattern1 pattern2 any text
pattern1 pattern2 any text
```

and I'll be applying this to thousands of lines

This command: `%s/\(pattern1\).\{-}\zs.\(pattern2\)\|\(pattern2\)/\r\1 \2 \3/g`

Is only producing:

```
pattern1 any text
pattern1 pattern2  any text
  pattern2 any text
  pattern2 any text
```

Because of the `\|` in the search string I think.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

That answer works for plain text, but not for patterns - you can't have patterns in the replace string unless you use an evaluated expression \=.

I've figured this out:

```
:%s/pattern2/\="\r" . matchstr(getline('.'), 'pattern1') . submatch(0)/g
```

So in my actual file, I'd use

```
pattern1 = .\{-}:  (everything up to the first colon)
pattern2 = \d\+ \a\+: (a date in the format dd mmm:)
```

resulting in

```
:%s/\d\+ \a\+:/\="\r" . matchstr(getline('.'), '.\{-}:') . submatch(0)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just replace `pattern2` by `\n` `pattern1 pattern2`?

```
:%s/pattern2/\rpattern1 pattern2/g
```

or without repeating `pattern2`:

```
:%s/\(pattern2\)/\rpattern1 \1/g
```

Both change

```
pattern1 any text pattern2 any text pattern2 any text pattern2 any text
```

to

```
pattern1 any text 
pattern1 pattern2 any text 
pattern1 pattern2 any text 
pattern1 pattern2 any text
```